# IE <DOCTYPE html> defaults to quirksmode

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I'm making a wordpress theme, and in IE, on my homepage of the theme, everything is aligned left, but everything that should be centered is centered when viewing a page or post.

I have tried cutting out almost everything from the homepage and I still have not found the origin of this.

The weird thing is though, that using IE Developer Toolbar, setting the Document Mode to IE 8, makes it work like a charm. But by default, the Document Mode is Quirksmode (which makes no sense, since I use **DOCTYPE html**!

I tried using the X-UA Compatible metatag, but that did not do it either.

I'm afraid that I cannot provide enough code as it would simply be too much.

How can I force IE to not use Quirksmode? As I said, I tried everything I know, and everything I could find on google, and nothing helped.

Here are a few screenies that may help you understand my problem.

### Document Mode: Quirksmode (DEFAULT! PROBLEM!)

[image]

### Document Mode: IE 8 Standards (Fixes the problem, but not default!)

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are testing the page locally only, the odds are that IE uses Quirks Mode just because of that. Try uploading the page on a server, test again, and post the URL if problems remain. (It could be some typo in the doctype declaration.) See also the page http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ which describes, among other things, some of the fairly confusing features of IE in the Quirks Mode issue.

Comment: I currently do not have a server to test on - I do use Apache though, but the weird thing is that only using Dev Tools could I disable the default Quirksmode.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the exclamation point? It should be `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: Yes, I do have the exclamation point. SO does not allow it in the title though.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was - Jukka was correct about the local environment being quirked, but to solve it, I found that I had to place the X-UA-Compatible metatag as the first thing in the Head tag for it to work. I am however accepting Jukka's answer as it is the most informative one. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, change your doctype to

```
<!doctype html>
```

Instead of

```
<doctype html>
```

The first is the HTML5 doctype, the second doesn't exist.

Comment: StackOverflow did not allow ! in the title, so yes, the doctype is correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove any comments before the DOCTYPE tag.